# Where is the problem of the derivation of $\text{cis}(0)=\text{cis}(2\pi-6)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$\newcommand{\cis}{\text{cis}}$Let $\cis(\theta)=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$
Rule 1: $\cis(\theta)=\cis(\theta\pm2\pi k)$ forall $k\in\mathbb N$
Rule 2: $\cis(\theta)^x= \cis(x\theta)$

Then:
$$\begin{align}\cis(0)&=\cis(2\pi)\\
 \cis(0)^\pi&=cis(2\pi)^\pi\\
 \cis(0)^π&=cis(2\pi)^\pi\\
 \cis(0)&=\cis(2\pi\pi)\\
 \cis(0)&=\cis(2\pi\pi-6\pi)\ldots\text{Rule 1}(k=3)\\
 \frac{\cis(0)^1}\pi&=\cis(2\pi\pi-6\pi)^{1/\pi}\ldots\text{Rule 
 2}\left(x=\frac1\pi\right)\\
 \cis(0)&=\cis(2\pi-6)\ldots\text{Not right}
 \end{align}$$

If using exponential form: 
$e^{i0}=e^{i2\pi}$ 
$1^{\pi}=e^{i2\pi\pi}$ 
$1=e^{i(2\pi\pi-6\pi)}$ 
$1^{1/\pi}=e^{i(2\pi-6)}$

Comment: cis$(\theta)^n=$cis$(n\theta)$ works for natural numbers $n$

Comment: Rule two is false when $x$ is not a natural number.

Comment: I'm considering "works for natural numbers n" may be a convenient way to execute

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $(e^{i \theta})^n$ doesn't hold for $n \in \mathfrak{R}$?

Comment: Anindya Prithvi: (eiθ)n is used almost everywhere, indirect at least. Are there any 'officialer'  source? And, I had made a stronger claim to verify: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814040/claim-for-periodic-exponential-functions-all-numbers-are-equal-if-wrong-wher

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi If $n$ is an integer, then $\exp(i\theta)^n$ has a single value, and that value is $\exp(in\theta)$. But if $a\notin\mathbb{Z}$, then $\exp(i\theta)^{a}$ is not well-defined, one needs to specify the branch of the power function [if you view it as $z \mapsto z^{a}$ evaluated at $z=\exp(i\theta)$] or the logarithm of $\exp(i\theta)$ to use [if one views it as the exponential function $w\mapsto\exp(w\log\exp(i\theta))$ evaluated at $w=a$] to determine the value. One of the possible values is $\exp(ia\theta)$, but unless $a$ is an integer, you can't just assume it's that one.

Comment: That was an awesome explanation and probably solves the OP's query too. thanks  OP please check the comment by @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the general case, $(\operatorname{cis}\theta)^z$ has countably infinitely many values, and you are only considering a single one of these.

In general, $w^z$ is computed as $e^{z\log w}$, and $\log w$ is where these multiple values arise. It's due to the fact that $w\mapsto e^w$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$. So given one particular value $u + iv$ of $\log w$, then each of $u+iv+2\pi k i$ is also a value of $\log w$.

In your case, $\log e^{i\theta} = i\theta + 2\pi k i$ for integral $k$, so the values of (say) $(e^{0i})^{\pi}$ are $$e^{\pi(0i + 2\pi k i)}=e^{2k\pi^2i}$$
which are $1$, $\cos 2\pi^2\pm i\sin 2\pi^2$, $\cos 4\pi^2\pm i\sin 4\pi^2$, etc.; and it gets worse from there as you manipulate these values in successive equations.

Comment: I made a stronger claim: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814040/claim-for-periodic-exponential-functions-all-numbers-are-equal

Comment: See my answer to that question