# Periodic-exponential function is a constant function. If wrong, where?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $x,a,t∈ℝ$, function f is defined as follow:
P1: $f(x)= f(x+i*t)$ ... f is periodic, i∈ℤ
P2: $f(x)^a= f(a*x)$ ... f is such an exponential function

Lemma1: $∀a∈ℝ, f(x)=f(x+a*t)$ 
Proof:  $f(x)=f(x+a*t)$ 
<=> $f(x)^{1/a}=f(x+a*t)^{1/a}$ 
<=> $f(x/a)= f(x/a+t)$ ... From P2
<=> $f(x/a)= f(x/a)$ ... From P1
<=> true

Lemma2: $∀a,b∈ℝ, f(a)=f(b)$ 
Proof: $f(a)=f(b)$ 
<=> $f(a)=f(a+c)$   ... Assume c=b-a 
<=> $f(a)=f(a+y*t)$ ... Assume y=c/t 
<=> $f(a)=f(a)$     ... from Lemma1 
<=> true

Ex: $e^{i1}=e^{i2}$ (or in complex form)
Proof: Let $W(x)=e^{ix}$ then, 
$W(1)=W(2)$ 
<=> $W(1)=W(1+1)$ 
<=> $W(1)=W(1+2π*(1/2π))$ 
<=> $W(1)=W(1)$ ... From Lemma1 
<=> true

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please check whether the statement(title)  is true or false,  and where's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong because your Lemma 1 is false.

Assuming $t$ is the minimal nonzero period of $f$, then it is only true for integral $a$, certainly not for all real $a$. Otherwise, you would be claiming that $f(x)=f(x+\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon$ (by taking $a=\epsilon/t$), which is absurd.

Everything else hinges on this false lemma.

Comment: I don't understand your 'absurdity'. Please demonstrate a more specific example.

Comment: It’s absurd because it implies every periodic function is constant. For example, let $f = \chi_{\mathbb Z}$, the characteristic function of the integers, which is $1$ at each integer and zero elsewhere. Then $f$ has period $t=1$, and $f(0)=1\neq 0=f(1/2)$. Your lemma says we can take $x=0$ and $a=1/2$ to get $1=f(0)=f(x)=f(x+a\cdot t)=f(0+(1/2)\cdot 1)=f(1/2)=0$, which is absurd (i.e., a contradiction). Hence the lemma is false.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that kind of characteristic function, but the f you were using not seem to be a periodic function

Comment: Yes, it is. It is true that $f(x+1) = f(x)$ for all $x$. To see this, note that if $x$ is an integer then so is $x+1$, and $f(x+1) = 1 = f(x)$; if $x$ is not an integer, then neither is $x+1$, and $f(x+1) = 0 = f(x)$. The graph of $f$ looks like a flat line along the $x$-axis except it jumps to $1$ at each integer.

Comment: Generally speaking for a set $S\subset \mathbb R$, the characteristic function $\chi_S$ is $1$ on $S$ and $0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$. It basically is a boolean function telling whether or not any particular $x$ is in $S$, so $\chi_S(x) = 1$ if $x\in S$ and $\chi_S(x)= 0$ if $X\notin S$. This is sometimes called an "indicator function", often denoted $\mathbf{1}_S$.

Comment: OK. Learned one. But, does it satisfy f(x)^a=f(a∗x)

Answer (score 0):

You leave unclear what the codomain of $f$ is; that is, what sort of values $f(x)$ might be.  **If $f(x)$ is real, then your claims are *essentially* correct**; there are no continuous periodic exponentials.

**But the more interesting scenario is if $f(x)$ might be any complex number.**  In that case, lemma 1 is false, because it assumes there is a unique $\frac{1}{a}$th root of $f(x)$ (and conversely, a unique $a$th root too!).  The problem is going from the second line of the proof (which is correct) backwards to the first.  If $a=\frac{1}{2}$, say, then you are trying to show $${f(x)^2=f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\Rightarrow f(x)=f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$  This is obviously false: $f(x)$ and $f\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ might differ by a sign!

**In general, you should be careful about taking powers and roots in your proofs.**  The implication almost always runs in one direction, not both (as you claimed here).

If $a=\frac{1}{4}$, each side might differ by a power of $i$.  If $a$ is irrational, there are infinitely many possibilities.  In fact, over the complex numbers, the only periodic exponentials are of the form $x\mapsto e^{n\pi i x}$, where $n$ is some integer.  It's easy to see that the LHS and RHS *do* differ by these multiplicative factors for functions of that sort.

(**Why did I say your claims are "essentially" correct?**  Working over the reals, you'll notice the flaw above is still there if $a$ is a dyadic fraction.  But continuity comes to the rescue: the nondyadic reals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so the values of $f$ on those points uniquely determines the function as a whole.  Your argument works on that smaller set.)

Comment: Indeed, deduction 2^2=(-2)^2 => 2=-2 is invalid. But most steps in the proof follows the axiom of equivalence. LHS and RHS are treated as black box. So, I just guess the codomain could be wider, but not explored.
As you mentioned e^(nπix) is the only possible only periodic exponentials, I made another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816409/why-cant-i-define-i-frac2x-pi-cosxi-sinx